# Click on created elements on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, click

How to use/detect click on iframe?
Element is freshly (live) created...

```
$('iframe').contents().find('.created').on('click', ...
```

Code above doesn't work.

Comment: is iframe on same domain? Are you calling this code after iframe loads? Not much information given

Comment: The same domain, iframe is loaded, class .created is added later

Comment: delegate to iframe document then or element that does exist that `created` will be within

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting the parent of the element first and see if that works.

```
$('iframe').contents().find('.parent-of-created').on('click', '.created', function(e){
    //some stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a parent function.

In your iframe script put something like this:

```
$('.created').on('click', function(){
  parent.functionName();
}
```

Later in your main script domain can handle as u want.

```
var functionName = function(){
  // Do something
}
```